# Capital gains and income

Tags: income-tax, income, capital-gain, new-zealand

When capital gains are not considered as an income (as per New Zealand Income Tax Law to be precise) then why capital gains/losses end up in an income statement to calculate net income?
Does that look contradictory to the tax law or I am confused with the concept. Thanks.

Comment: According to the [NZ goverment site](https://www.newzealandnow.govt.nz/living-in-nz/money-tax/nz-tax-system#section--7) capital gains tax is applied to foreign bond and equity investments.  Perhaps your shares are in funds with foreign holdings?

Comment: Who is generating the income statement?